# No Internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, connection

I installed Ubuntu next to Windows for one system because windows sucks but u want to hold it for games. But that's not the problem about. My problem is, that I don't get any Internet connection or a connection to my router. But on Windows everything is fine. On my ifconfig is one eth0 without any a dresses except the MAC adress. The other return I got is the lo, and it returns an inet adress of localhost (127.0.0.1). I really don't know what to do now :(

---

What about my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf? One line is:

```
no-auto-default=FF:AA:14:91:DC:ED
```

Is that right or wrong? For me it seems to be wrong because of no and default :'D

This is my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf now:

```
[main] 
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
COUNTRY=DE
#dns=dnsmaq

#no-auto-default=FC:AA:14:91:DC:ED,

[ifupdown] 
managed=false

[keyfile] 
hostname=Max-PC
```

Comment: Di you connect to your router by wire or wifi?

Comment: It's cable to a TP-Link and then from TP-Link to cable to router

Comment: So it's actually going through the electricity of our house

Comment: The line "no-auto-default" is commented out with a # and so the line is not active and is not in use so it doesn't matter. The file looks fine except, you have dnsmasq commented out. Unless you have another means of providing dns, you may need that.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and make sure it has `auto eth0` or something similar like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet loopback

iface eth0 inet
       managed true
       dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

Change the nameserver accordingly if you don't want to use google-dns. 8.8.4.4 is just an example that should work fine if used.

Then, restart network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

---

**EDIT**

First of all, the wait time for `waiting for networking resources` may seem like it takes forever but is only set to 60 or 90 seconds by default. Just be patient and run the following command when the system *finally* does boot to prevent this in the future:

```
sudo sed -e 's/sleep.../sleep 1/g' /etc/init/failsafe.conf
```

Additionally, you should probably post the entire contents of your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file. You may omit the hostname line if you feel you need to for privacy reasons. or just change the line to `hostname=hostname` and we'll get the drift.

As far as the line: `no-auto-default=FF:AA:14:91:DC:ED` is concerned, I don't see a similar line in my file so it's probably best to comment that line out.

Here's an example of what a functioning file looks like:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
COUNTRY=US

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
hostname=$HOSTNAME
```

Replace `$HOSTNAME` with your *actual* hostname. To print your hostname, run the following command:

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

Also, replace `COUNTRY=US` with your actual country code or comment this line out.

Additionally, make sure ports 67 and 68 are open for DHCP and also make sure port 53 is open for DNS. Additionally without being said, you need ports 80 and 443 open for http and https.

However, these ports *should not* be blocked by default so unless you messed around with your firewall settings, you shouldn't have to adjust these settings. [See here for more info.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall)

Comment: I opened the file and changed it as you said but nothing changed...

Comment: Now I restarted My computer and it doesn't even boot, it is waiting for networking resources...

Comment: @Max you should be patient, this wait time is set to 60 seconds by default. To disable this, run the following command: `sudo sed -e 's/sleep.../sleep 1/g' /etc/init/failsafe.conf` Also, I have edited the answer.

Comment: This is my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf :

Comment: I would be still happy about an answer because this is making me crazy...